# QFont.setFamily() not working with custom font

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I was trying to make nice GUI for my program and I knew I needed a cool font as well. So I installed the 'Ubuntu' font with all weights.

But when I try this:

```
class MenuButton(QPushButton):
    def __init__(self, caption):
        super().__init__()
        self.setFixedHeight(60)
        self.setFixedWidth(100)
        self.setFlat(True)
        font = QFont()
        font.setFamily('Ubuntu')
        font.setWeight(QFont.Bold)
        font.setPixelSize(20)
        self.setFont(font)
        self.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(85,170,255);")
        self.setText(caption)
```

I get a font which pretty sure isn't what I picked:

[image]

But when I summon a `QFontDialog` at the start of my app however, I can see Ubuntu font and it IS named Ubuntu!

[image]

Why isn't it working and what am I supposed to do for it to work?

Appreciate the help...

Here is all:

```
import sys
import _thread
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize, Qt, QRect, QObject
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QProgressBar, QLabel, QTabWidget, QGridLayout, QVBoxLayout, \
QHBoxLayout, QSizePolicy, QSpacerItem, QStyle, QStyleFactory, QPushButton, QFrame, QFontDialog, QStackedWidget
from PyQt5.QtGui import QImage, QIcon, QPixmap, QPalette, QBrush, QColor, QFontDatabase, QFont

### Custom Classes

class MenuButton(QPushButton):
    def __init__(self, caption):
        super().__init__()
        self.setFixedHeight(40)
        self.setFixedWidth(100)
        self.setFlat(True)
        font = QFont()
        font.setFamily('Ubuntu')
        font.setWeight(QFont.Bold)
        font.setPixelSize(19)
        self.setFont(QFont('Ubuntu', 19, QFont.Medium))
        self.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(85,170,255);")
        self.setText(caption)

    def select(self):
        self.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(255,255,255);")
    def deselect(self):
        self.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(85,170,255);")

class StackPage(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setStyleSheet('background-color: rgb(28,33,39)')
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

class MainScreen(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        #self.windowWidth = 500
        #self.windowHeight = 300

        self.icon = 'images\\system\\HashshashinLogo.png'
        self.title = 'DevOrder'

        self.fontFamily = 'Segoe UI' # Corbel | Sagoe UI
        self.fontColor = 'black'
        self.fontSize = '12'

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        self.setStyleSheet('font-family: %s; color: %s; background-color: rgb(28,33,39);' % (self.fontFamily, self.fontColor))
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon(self.icon))
        #self.setFixedSize(self.windowWidth, self.windowHeight)

        ### Top Menu

        def menubtnProjectsClicked():
            menubtnProjects.select()
            menubtnClients.deselect()
            menubtnUpdates.deselect()
            menubtnSettings.deselect()
            self.leftStackMenu.setCurrentIndex(0)
        def menubtnClientsClicked():
            menubtnProjects.deselect()
            menubtnClients.select()
            menubtnUpdates.deselect()
            menubtnSettings.deselect()
            self.leftStackMenu.setCurrentIndex(1)
        def menubtnUpdatesClicked():
            menubtnProjects.deselect()
            menubtnClients.deselect()
            menubtnUpdates.select()
            menubtnSettings.deselect()
            self.leftStackMenu.setCurrentIndex(2)
        def menubtnSettingsClicked():
            menubtnProjects.deselect()
            menubtnClients.deselect()
            menubtnUpdates.deselect()
            menubtnSettings.select()
            self.leftStackMenu.setCurrentIndex(3)

        menubtnProjects = MenuButton('Projects')
        menubtnProjects.clicked.connect(menubtnProjectsClicked)
        menubtnClients = MenuButton('Clients')
        menubtnClients.clicked.connect(menubtnClientsClicked)
        menubtnUpdates = MenuButton('Updates')
        menubtnUpdates.clicked.connect(menubtnUpdatesClicked)
        menubtnSettings = MenuButton('Settings')
        menubtnSettings.clicked.connect(menubtnSettingsClicked)

        ### Left Menu

        self.leftStackMenu = QStackedWidget()
        self.leftStackMenu.setFixedWidth(500)

        leftProjectsPage = StackPage()
        leftProjectsPage.setStyleSheet('background-color: white;')
        leftClientsPage = StackPage()
        leftClientsPage.setStyleSheet('background-color: red;')
        leftUpdatesPage = StackPage()
        leftUpdatesPage.setStyleSheet('background-color: blue;')
        leftSettingsPage = StackPage()
        leftSettingsPage.setStyleSheet('background-color: yellow;')

        self.leftStackMenu.addWidget(leftProjectsPage)
        self.leftStackMenu.addWidget(leftClientsPage)
        self.leftStackMenu.addWidget(leftUpdatesPage)
        self.leftStackMenu.addWidget(leftSettingsPage)



        ### Placings

        menuLayout = QHBoxLayout()
        menuLayout.setContentsMargins(50, 10, 10, 10)
        menuLayout.addWidget(menubtnProjects)
        menuLayout.addWidget(menubtnClients)
        menuLayout.addWidget(menubtnUpdates)
        menuLayout.addWidget(menubtnSettings)
        menuLayout.addSpacerItem(QSpacerItem(20, 40, QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Minimum))

        stacksLayout = QHBoxLayout()
        stacksLayout.addWidget(self.leftStackMenu)

        menuWidget = QWidget()
        menuWidget.setStyleSheet('background-color: rgb(22,26,31);')
        menuWidget.setLayout(menuLayout)

        mainLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        mainLayout.addWidget(menuWidget)
        mainLayout.addLayout(stacksLayout)
        mainLayout.addSpacerItem(QSpacerItem(20, 40, QSizePolicy.Minimum, QSizePolicy.Expanding))
        mainLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.setLayout(mainLayout)
        #self.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    #print('Currently used style:', app.style().metaObject().className())
    #print('Available styles:', QStyleFactory.keys())
    app.setStyle(QStyleFactory().create('windowsvista'))
    QFontDialog().getFont()
    loadingScreen = LoadingScren()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Very simple, just use this line of code self.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Ubuntu", 20, QtGui.QFont.Normal, Bold=True))

Comment: what is the problem ?, according to the image I see that it is working correctly.

Comment: @Zar Kha It didn't work. Besides there was no kwargument such as Bold. QFont('Ubuntu', 19, QFont.Bold) didn't work either.

Comment: Provide your entire code.

Comment: @Zar Kha Mattering part added...

Comment: @Hashshashin `self.setFont(QFont('Ubuntu', 19, QFont.Medium))`  or  `self.setFont(QFont('Ubuntu', 19, QFont.Bold))`???

Comment: @ZarKha Nope :(

Comment: @Hashshashin. I would look at it :)

Comment: @Hashshashin. Your code this line gives error `loadingScreen = LoadingScren()`.  where is this class or function?

Answer (score 0):

To solve your problem, we need to change slightly your code. 
First you add this line code `self.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Ubuntu", 20, QtGui.QFont.Bold))` under `class MenuButton()`.

Remember to show mainwindow, that you would do by adding this code

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle(QtWidgets.QStyleFactory().create('windowsvista'))
    win = MainScreen()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Window with correct font after launch

[image]

**The code**

```
import sys
import _thread
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

### Custom Classes

class MenuButton(QtWidgets.QPushButton):
    def __init__(self, caption):
        super(MenuButton, self).__init__()

        self.setFlat(True)
        self.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Ubuntu", 20, QtGui.QFont.Bold))
        self.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(85,170,255);")
        self.setText(caption)

    def select(self):
        self.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(255,255,255);")
    def deselect(self):
        self.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(85,170,255);")

class StackPage(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setStyleSheet('background-color: rgb(28,33,39)')
        self.layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

class MainScreen(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainScreen, self).__init__(parent)

        #self.windowWidth = 500
        #self.windowHeight = 300

        self.icon = 'images\\system\\HashshashinLogo.png'
        self.title = 'DevOrder'

        self.fontFamily = 'Segoe UI' # Corbel | Sagoe UI
        self.fontColor = 'black'
        self.fontSize = '12'

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        self.setStyleSheet('font-family: %s; color: %s; background-color: rgb(28,33,39);' % (self.fontFamily, self.fontColor))
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon(self.icon))
        #self.setFixedSize(self.windowWidth, self.windowHeight)

        ### Top Menu

        def menubtnProjectsClicked():
            menubtnProjects.select()
            menubtnClients.deselect()
            menubtnUpdates.deselect()
            menubtnSettings.deselect()
            self.leftStackMenu.setCurrentIndex(0)
        def menubtnClientsClicked():
            menubtnProjects.deselect()
            menubtnClients.select()
            menubtnUpdates.deselect()
            menubtnSettings.deselect()
            self.leftStackMenu.setCurrentIndex(1)
        def menubtnUpdatesClicked():
            menubtnProjects.deselect()
            menubtnClients.deselect()
            menubtnUpdates.select()
            menubtnSettings.deselect()
            self.leftStackMenu.setCurrentIndex(2)
        def menubtnSettingsClicked():
            menubtnProjects.deselect()
            menubtnClients.deselect()
            menubtnUpdates.deselect()
            menubtnSettings.select()
            self.leftStackMenu.setCurrentIndex(3)

        menubtnProjects = MenuButton('Projects')
        menubtnProjects.clicked.connect(menubtnProjectsClicked)
        menubtnClients = MenuButton('Clients')
        menubtnClients.clicked.connect(menubtnClientsClicked)
        menubtnUpdates = MenuButton('Updates')
        menubtnUpdates.clicked.connect(menubtnUpdatesClicked)
        menubtnSettings = MenuButton('Settings')
        menubtnSettings.clicked.connect(menubtnSettingsClicked)

        ### Left Menu

        self.leftStackMenu = QtWidgets.QStackedWidget()
        self.leftStackMenu.setFixedWidth(500)

        leftProjectsPage = StackPage()
        leftProjectsPage.setStyleSheet('background-color: white;')
        leftClientsPage = StackPage()
        leftClientsPage.setStyleSheet('background-color: red;')
        leftUpdatesPage = StackPage()
        leftUpdatesPage.setStyleSheet('background-color: blue;')
        leftSettingsPage = StackPage()
        leftSettingsPage.setStyleSheet('background-color: yellow;')

        self.leftStackMenu.addWidget(leftProjectsPage)
        self.leftStackMenu.addWidget(leftClientsPage)
        self.leftStackMenu.addWidget(leftUpdatesPage)
        self.leftStackMenu.addWidget(leftSettingsPage)



        ### Placings

        menuLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        menuLayout.setContentsMargins(50, 10, 10, 10)
        menuLayout.addWidget(menubtnProjects)
        menuLayout.addWidget(menubtnClients)
        menuLayout.addWidget(menubtnUpdates)
        menuLayout.addWidget(menubtnSettings)
        menuLayout.addSpacerItem(QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(20, 40, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum))

        stacksLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        stacksLayout.addWidget(self.leftStackMenu)

        menuWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        menuWidget.setStyleSheet('background-color: rgb(22,26,31);')
        menuWidget.setLayout(menuLayout)

        mainLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        mainLayout.addWidget(menuWidget)
        mainLayout.addLayout(stacksLayout)
        mainLayout.addSpacerItem(QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(20, 40, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding))
        mainLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.setLayout(mainLayout)
        #self.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle(QtWidgets.QStyleFactory().create('windowsvista'))
    win = MainScreen()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```